# Strange issue with Google

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, google-chrome, firefox

I have installed Ubuntu on my laptop. Now I have dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.10 both of them are x64 bits. I have two problems:

1. The first one is the I can't connect to their server from the Ubuntu machine, I don't have any problem while I use Windows. Firstly I'm rarely able to connect to Youtube however I'm able to connect to the search engine(they are hosted on the same machine according to my ping probes I can paste IP address if anyone wants to)
2. Secondly if I'm able to connect I get only text if I try to play a video I get "Video is unavailable". I thought it was from firefox(the browser I use). So I tried to install chrome. When I tried to download chrome a new window was opened with the url containing the file it was dl.google.com.... but at that time I was again unable to connect to Google after a few tries I was able to download and install it but the result was the same I still have a problem to access youtube. The strange thing is that I always have access to the search engine(which as I said is on the same server).

Any ideas from where this problem might come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this might be as issue with firewall or due to routing or restriction in routing. To check disable the iptables in Debian using the command below and verify whether you are able to access the youtube.

```
 sudo ufw disable
```

Note : Also try to pinging youtube from terminal and check whether you are getting success ping.

Comment: Hmm youtube's working now for first time today I hope this is solution to the problem. Thank you, if I have any problem I will write a commend here I hope you will receive it.

Comment: Happy to know that fixed your issue. yes, We are here to help and surely you will receive the guidance you :-)